# Javascript chart with multiple "chart areas"

Tags: javascript, charts

Can anyone suggest a Javascript chart library that could produce such chart: [Refer this Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2sy2hg48eej711/history-schedule-chart.png?dl=0)

The emphasis here is on two separate areas: history and schedule. Each of them should have a different title and background color. Basically, it would be great if each area is configurable separately.

I tried Google Charts but did not see how to implement it in a clean way. I could create two charts with a specific layout, but I would prefer a more dynamic and correct way of doing that.

Comment: If it is possible than edit your code in Jsfiddle and share here

Comment: I got it working with Google Charts API, see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uyjqgLob/1/ . Basically the idea is to combine several charts by just leaving the chart area and horizontal axis visible. Some titles and legends will have to be rendered outside the actual chart.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a charting library to accomplish this, [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) would do the trick. By setting "layout" in the graphset object to "x2" and creating two separate chart objects, your charts are set up side-by-side but can still be manipulated individually. I've included a demo below for reference. Run it to see the chart.

You can download the entire library for free on the site. If you have any questions, I'm on the team and happy to help! You can reach us at support@zingchart.com.

```js
var myChart = {
    "layout":"x2",
    "background-color":"#eee",
    "border-color":"#000",
    "border-width":2,
    "graphset":[
        {
            "type":"bar",
            "background-color":"#eee",
            "width":"60%",
            "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "title":{
                "text":"Chart 1",
                "text-align":"left",
                "font-color":"black",
                "background-color":"#ddd"
            },
            "scale-x":{
                "values":["2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"],
                "label":{
                    "text":"History",
                    "offset-x":-125,
                    "padding-top":10
                },
                "tick":{
                    "visible":false
                    },
                "guide":{
                    "visible":false
                    }
            },
            "scale-y":{
                    "values":"0:12:2",
                    "guide":{
                        "line-style":"solid"
                        }
                },
            "plot":{
                "stacked":true
                },
            "plotarea":{
                "margin-right":0,
                "background-color":"#ddd"
            },
            "legend":{
                "shared":true,
                "visible":false
            },
            "series":[
             {
          "values":[3,5,5,5,8,6,4,3],
                "background-color":"#018BD3"
             },
          {
       "values":[null,null,null,null,3,null,null,null],
                "background-color":"#F27D30"
             },
          {
          "values":[],
                "background-color":"#F2D134"
          },
             {
          "values":[null,null,null,null,null,2,null,2],
                "background-color":"#14AE13"
             }
         ]
        },
        {
            "type":"bar",
            "background-color":"#eee",
            "width":"40%",
            "x":"60%",
            "y":0,
             "title":{
                "text":"Chart 2",
                "text-align":"left",
                "font-color":"black",
                "background-color":"#ccc"
            },
            "scale-x":{
                "values":["2015","2016","2017"],
                "tick":{
                    "visible":false
                    },
                "guide":{
                    "visible":false
                    },
                "label":{
                    "text":"Schedule",
                    "offset-x":-25,
                    "padding-top":10
                }
            },
            "scale-y":{
                    "values":"0:12:2",
                    "line-color":"#777",
                    "tick":{
                        "visible":false
                        },
                    "item":{
                        "visible":false
                        },
                    "guide":{
                        "line-style":"solid"
                        }
                },
            "plot":{
                "stacked":true
                },
            "plotarea":{
                "margin-left":0,
                "margin-right":"50%",
                "background-color":"#ccc"
                },
            "legend":{
                "shared":true
            },
            "series":[
                {
          "values":[7,1,0],
                "background-color":"#018BD3"
             },
          {
       "values":[],
                "background-color":"#F27D30"
             },
          {
          "values":[3,6,1],
                "background-color":"#F2D134"
          },
             {
          "values":[1,null,null],
                "background-color":"#14AE13"
             }
         ]
        }
    ]
};

  zingchart.render({
            id : "myChart",
            height : "300px",
            width : "100%",
            data : myChart
        });
```

```html
<script src="http://www.zingchart.com/playground/lib/zingchart/zingchart-html5-min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [d3Js - examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) library.

The possible solution is you have to define Two graph separately with using `<div>` tag.

Give each of them separate CSS values (for colors and your specific needs), And then define both `<div>` under single division.

First try to edit [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardikanavadia/dScZf/97/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-installation/) library. We have an extensive dashboard API which allows you to group multiple independent and customizable charts into a layout which can then also be resized on the fly.
You should take a look at our interactive examples for this specific use case [Dashboard Example](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0502-dashboardTrading.html).

Full disclosure: I am a developer for LightningChart, I think you may find this very useful.